# How to debug performance issues using android default browser (Galaxy S3)

Tags: javascript, android, html, performance-testing, android-browser

Google chrome provides remote debugging, which is how I normally debug on my Galaxy S3, but I have now come across a problem with loading speed and javascript lag that appears only to happen in the default browser and not in Chrome.

Can anyone suggest any tools/methods for testing with the default browser.